# UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera - add "library" button in lower-left corner

Tags: iphone, ios4

I've seen that when some apps display the default ImagePicker, they have a button in lower-left corner of the screen with a small picture minature. Upon clicking it user is presented with his library to choose the picture from.

So, I'm running the ImagePicker like this:

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

What do I need to add to this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is most likely done using the `cameraOverlayView` property of the image picker controller. Any view you assign to that property will be displayed on top of the normal camera interface.

Comment: Is it? the icon that is visible in these apps contains the most recent photo from the library. I don't think you can create a button that can contain such a photo (without user explicitly selecting that photo). Or am I wrong?

Comment: You could use [AssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730) to get the ALAssetsGroup for the Camera Roll and use the `posterImage` property to do such a thing.